# Visual Studio Code, Python debug not working

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I am using the conda distribution of Visual Studio Code for writing Python .py files.I have selected the conda python interpreter. I have the python extension installed, and am launching the debug python in the integratedConsole with the default settings:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
},
```

However, when I set a break point anywhere, the debug session does not break and continues to run until all the code has been executed.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow When I encountered this issue I decided to use an alternative IDE and have not looked back since. Although I still use VSCODE for some things.

Comment: For anyone facing this problem, i found this work around solution from microsoft - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7836#issuecomment-540350986

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which IDE did you switch to.
Is it as good as VSCode?